# JHipster Gateway restarts

Tags: jhipster, microservices, gateway

I'm developing an application with JHipster infrastructure, and as a newbie with this set of tools, I don't know why my gateway is not working as expected.

I use a custom development profile (devh2) and I launch application with it (mvnw -Pdevh2).

It restarts randomly and I don't know why... ^^!

After a few seconds of being started (it has been registered ok at registry server), it shows this:

```
DEBUG 59072 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] e.j.u.g.a.AccessControlFilter            : Access Control: allowing access for /userback/api/account, as no access control policy has been set up for service: userback
WARN 59072 --- [rixMetricPoller] com.netflix.spectator.api.Spectator      : no config impl found in classpath, using default
DEBUG 59072 --- [  XNIO-2 task-4] e.j.u.g.a.AccessControlFilter            : Access Control: allowing access for /userback/api/rols, as no access control policy has been set up for service: userback
WARN 59072 --- [       Thread-2] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1513153436519, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
INFO 59072 --- [       Thread-2] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
INFO 59072 --- [       Thread-2] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
WARN 59072 --- [nfoReplicator-0] o.s.b.a.h.ElasticsearchHealthIndicator   : Health check failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Future got interrupted
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:72)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:99)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1362)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:100)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:68)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

It tries to restart but....

```
INFO 59072 --- [  restartedMain] es.jumbo.userfront.UserfrontApp          : The following profiles are active: swagger,devh2
ERROR 59072 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.<init>(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.<init>(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:56)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:635)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at es.jumbo.userfront.UserfrontApp.main(UserfrontApp.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

The launcher class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(UserfrontApp.class);
    DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
    Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
    String protocol = "http";
    if (env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store") != null) {
        protocol = "https";
    }
    log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
            "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
            "Local: \t\t{}://localhost:{}\n\t" +
            "External: \t{}://{}:{}\n\t" +
            "Profile(s): \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
        env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
        protocol,
        env.getProperty("server.port"),
        protocol,
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
        env.getProperty("server.port"),
        env.getActiveProfiles());

    String configServerStatus = env.getProperty("configserver.status");
    log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
            "Config Server: \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
        configServerStatus == null ? "Not found or not setup for this application" : configServerStatus);
}
```

The line where the party starts is

```
Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
```

However, args has just one property setted: --spring.profiles.active=devh2

After the restart attempt, application unregisters from registry server.

Does anyone know, why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

**SOLVED**

I really don't know the reason, but empty my maven local repository and re-launching all the actors (registry, gateway & microservices), everything works as expected (all dependencies has been downloaded again). When I had more time, I'll try to deep search in why this was happening, but I think git branches are the responsible. Probably another branch could have download a different library, or a different library version

Comment: What's the purpose of this custom profile devh2? How does it differ from dev profile? Profiles are used by the registry to serve application properties, have you defined a yaml file for this profile?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I have a yaml file for this new profile (application-devh2.yml). The purpose is having two different development infrastucture, as some of project developers work from remote, and the rest, phisically at the office. Remote developers work without proxy and using h2 database. The rest work under a proxy and with a db2 database.

Comment: You should have combined with dev `--spring.profiles.active=dev,devh2`, by overriding only the differences in app*-devh2.yml and benefit from all the JHipster behavior for dev. Here we can only guess that you did not forget to modify all parts (build, code in java and js, registry) that depend on dev, so I doubt you can get help. Dev is not only about environment, it's also about behavior.

Comment: Already solved. Thank you very much

Comment: Even if it is solved, I still think it's not the best practice as I explained above, you may have problem when you upgrade jhipster in your apps.